# How to construct Polyphase (Frank) codes in MATLAB

Tags: autocorrelation

I have written a piece of code in MATLAB to [generate Frank codes - *Pastebin link*](http://pastebin.com/bbC9ZEbF) for pulse compression.

I know that Frank codes are stepped frequency approximations to Linear Frequency modulation(LFM).

LFM Parameters are obtained here:

```
PW = 100e-6;% Pulse Width
PCR = 100; % Pulse Compression Ratio
CPW = PW/PCR;% Compressed pulse width
Fm = 2/CPW; %Frequency sweep
```

- Stepped frequency approximation to LFM:

  ```
  steppedFreq = 0:Fm/(N-1):Fm;
  ```
- The phase matrix is generated in the line:

  ```
  Matrix = mod(Matrix*incPhi,360);
  ```
- Frank code is generated inside the for loop:

  ```
  FCP = [FCP,exp(1j*(2*pift + Matrix(i,p)*pi/180))];
  ```
- The autocorrelation in dB is calculated here:

  ```
  AutoCorrelationdB = 20*log10(abs(AutoCorrelation)/max(abs(AutoCorrelation)));
  ```

**My question:**

The Peak side lobe level obtained is only around $3.5\textrm{ dB}$. Am I following a correct method for generating Frank codes? The peak side lobe level is given by the formula `20*log10(1/(N*sin(pi/M)))` as per the book [Principles of Modern Radar: Basic Principles by M.A. Richards - Page 825](http://www.scitechpub.com/pomr/) which is equal to $29\textrm{ dB}$ for my case($N = 100,M = 10$).

Comment: MATLAB programming questions are off-topic for this site. Please ask the moderators to migrate this to stackoverflow.SE or another SE site for programming questions.

Comment: I believe that this question has enough of DSP in it, to be answered on DSP SE (we do not lack great programmers here).

Comment: Plot of the ACF shows lots of ripples (which you seem to be interpreting as side-lobes). Looking at `plot(real(FCP))` and `plot(imag(FCP))` shows a lot of phase discontinuities which is probably partly responsible for the ripples. Though am I still getting strong peaks (not ripples) when removing those phase discontinuities (maybe I did something wrong, perhaps someone would have better luck there, or at least be able to explain why those peaks are there).

Comment: It looks like you've incorporated parts of the Answer to your code in PasteBin, right? Either way, thanks for making the code available, nice implementation in Matlab.

Answer (score -1):

```
% created by MUSTAFA SAMI AHMED
% Email mustafa_sami87@yahoo.com
clc;
clear all;
M =100;
L=sqrt(M);
bv = 0:L-1;
Matrix = bv'*bv ;
anglout = radtodeg(pi);
% alfa= (4*pi)/(L);

% Matrix_new = alfa*Matrix; 
incPhi = (2*pi)/L; %incremental phase change
Matrix = mod(Matrix*incPhi,2*pi);

b=reshape(Matrix,1,[]); % matrix 1D size 1xM
for p = 1:M
  d(p) = exp(1j*b(p)) ;
end    

AutoCorrelation = xcorr(d);

AutoCorrelationdB =10*log10(abs(AutoCorrelation)/max(abs(AutoCorrelation)));
 figure(1);
 stem(b);
%   x=wden(AutoCorrelationdB,'heursure','h','mln',10,'sym10');
  %x=wiener2(AutoCorrelationdB, [3 80 ]);
  figure(2);
plot((AutoCorrelationdB));
```

Comment: And what is that?